# Postgres migration

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, migration

I am trying to add column to the table from .Net to the Postgres by migration. while update-database I had an error says unrelated table name already exist. It is not even table that I am trying add column? How can I fix that issue? Thank you in advance for your response

Failed executing DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE "Customers" (
"Id" uuid NOT NULL,
"Name" text NULL,
"CreateDate" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
"UpdatedDate" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "PK_Customers" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);

This is the error. But I am trying to add column another name table

Also this 42P07: relation "Customers" already exists

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the SQL code that fails and the exact and _complete_ error message you get. Please provide the code as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) - [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please

Comment: Are you making migrations using Entity Framework Core? Because then it is an issue with the database schema state not being what EF core expected. You may want to check what migrations have been applied according to the table `__EFMigrationsHistory` in your database.

Comment: Hi, yes it in added and show up overthere however does not in the database